# Using csr_matrix of items similarities to get most similar items to item X without having to transform csr_matrix to dense matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, cosine-similarity

I have a purchase data (**df_temp**). I managed to replace using Pandas Dataframe to using a sparse csr_matrix because I have lots of products (89000) which I have to get their user-item information (purchased or not purchased) and then calculate the similarities between products.

First, I converted Pandas DataFrame to Numpy array:

```
 df_user_product = df_temp[['user_id','product_id']].copy()
 ar1 = np.array(df_user_product.to_records(index=False))
```

Second, created a [coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) because it's known for being fast in sparse matrix construction.

```
 rows, r_pos = np.unique(ar1['product_id'], return_inverse=True)
 cols, c_pos = np.unique(ar1['user_id'], return_inverse=True)
 s = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(r_pos.shape,int), (r_pos, c_pos)))
```

Third, for matrix calculations, it's better to use csr_matrix or [csc_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html), so I used [csr_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) as I have the product_id(s) in rows => more effective row slicing than csc_matrix.

```
    sparse_csr_mat = s.tocsr()
    sparse_csr_mat[sparse_csr_mat > 1] = 1
```

Then, I calculated the **[cosine similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627219/whats-the-fastest-way-in-python-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-sparse-mat)** between products and put the result in **similarities**:

```
import sklearn.preprocessing as pp
col_normed_mat = pp.normalize(sparse_csr_mat, axis=1)
similarities = col_normed_mat * col_normed_mat.T
```

Which is:

```
<89447x89447 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1332945 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Now, I want to have at the end a dictionary where for each product, there is the 5 most similar products. How to do it? I don't want to convert the sparse matrix to a dense array because of memory usage constraints. But I also didn't know if there is a way to access the csr_matrix like we do for array where we check for example index=product_id and get all the rows where the index=product_id, that way I will get all the similar products to product_id and sort by cosine similarity value to get the 5 most similar.

For example, a row in similarities matrix:

`(product_id1, product_id2) 0.45`

how to filter on only the X (=5 in my case) most similar products to product_id1, without having to convert the matrix to an array?

Looking in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545775/item-to-item-collaborative-filtering-how-to-manage-similarity-matrix), I think lil_matrix can be used for this case? how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A minor point, `sparse.csr_matrix(...)` takes the same inputs as `coo_matrix`.  `coo` format is, in effect, a raw data format, which for almost all calculations is converted to `csr` format. Often that conversion is automatic.  But to do things like indexing, you do need the `csr` format.

Comment: It might help if you demonstrated what you want to do with a small dense array.

Comment: You could do a `M = ...tolil()` and look at the `M.rows`.  That'll be an array of lists of the column indices.  Or get the `lil` of the transpose, to get lists of row indices.

Comment: There have been questions about getting the top N values per row of sparse matrices, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207275/finding-the-top-n-values-in-a-row-of-a-scipy-sparse-matrix.  Same thing applied to a `csc` can get the top values per column.

Comment: @hpaulj I don't understand what you mean by automatic conversion of `coo_matrix` to `csr_matrix` when doing calculations. In the documentations it's mentioned that coo_matrix is not as effective in calculations and better use csr.

Comment: I checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52304675/6837132 but the problem I don't understand what `indptr` of `csr_matrix` returns ..

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood how I can get the 5 most similar items to each products and this is by using `.tolil()` matrix and then convert each row to a numpy array and use `argsort` to get the 5 most similar items. I used @hpaulj solution suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135927/get-top-n-items-of-every-row-in-a-scipy-sparse-matrix).

```
def max_n(row_data, row_indices, n):
        i = row_data.argsort()[-n:]
        # i = row_data.argpartition(-n)[-n:]
        top_values = row_data[i]
        top_indices = row_indices[i]  # do the sparse indices matter?

        return top_values, top_indices, i
```

and then I applied it to one row for testing:

```
top_v, top_ind, ind = max_n(np.array(arr_ll.data[0]),np.array(arr_ll.rows[0]),5)
```

What I need is the `top_indices` which are the indices of the 5 most similar products, but those indices are not the real `product_id`. I mapped them when I constructed the `coo_matrix`

```
rows, r_pos = np.unique(ar1['product_id'], return_inverse=True)
```

But how to get the real `product_id` back from the indices?

Now for example I have:

```
top_ind = [2 1 34 9 123]
```

How to know `2` correspond to what `product_id`, `1` to what, etc?